# Как узнать, можно ли разыменовать указатель?

Tags: c++, c

У меня возникла некоторая проблема: у меня в одной части программы используется объдинение из указателя char* и просто char. Хотелось бы вывести оба этих элемента (по-разному их интерпретируя, разумеется). Но, если в объединении хранится символ, указатель разыменовывать нельзя — иначе упадём. Как заранее выяснить, не приведёт ли разыменовывание к сегфолту?

Кончено, можно было бы завести рядышком специальное поле, в котором хранить информацию о том, что лежит в объединии. Но для этого нужно переписать большую часть кода, что вряд ли подходит, и, наверняка, есть менее глобальное решение.

Comment: можно попробовать использовать простой трюк - так как символ скорее всего будет иметь код до 255, а указатель в пределах первого мегабайта с большой вероятностью невалидный, то обычный if поможет. Но это костыль.

Comment: @KoVadim, код символа надо обеспечить. Если там был указатель, а мы один байт из 4 или 8 затёрли символом, то число по-прежнему больше 256, и, скорее всего, по-прежнему является валидным указателем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот есть один способ, правда, он непереносим и будет работать лишь на Linux. Нужно посмотреть на таблицу памяти, выделеной процессу. Если область памяти, на которую указывает указатель, помечена как доступная для чтения, значит, оный указатель можно разыменовать, и вывести содержимое той памяти. Если же нужно записать что-то в эту память, следует смотреть на второй флаг.

Конечно, такой вариант скорее подходит лишь для целей отладки. Но, возможно, и на других системах можно как-нибудь выяснить корректность указателя.

Идея кода была взята из [исходников](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/procps.git/tree/pmap.c?id=200614187996b9bdbc5a70c7a94282894dc5cb3d#n514) утилиты pmap. Подробнее о формате файла `/proc/self/maps` можно почитать в справочном руководстве [**proc**(5)](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?category=5&russian=&topic=proc).

```c
bool can_i_read(void* p)
{
    uintptr_t begin, end;
    char readable, writable, executable, mapped;
    FILE* fp = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        return false;
    }
    while (fscanf(fp, "%" SCNxPTR "-%" SCNxPTR " %c%c%c%c",
            &begin, &end, &readable, &writable, &executable, &mapped) == 6) {
        if (begin <= (uintptr_t)p && (uintptr_t)p < end) {
            fclose(fp);
            // если нужно проверить доступность на запись,
            // следует смотреть флаг writable
            return readable == 'r';
        }
        // не зациклимся — перед концом всегда будет перевод строки
        while (fgetc(fp) != '\n')
            ;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return false;
}
```

Работоспособность проверена на Ubuntu 14.04.4 / Linux 4.1.15

Comment: Тут только возникает вопрос о времени работы такой проверки. Понятно, что если проверка единична, то этим можно пренебречь. А если речь о тысячах точек?

Comment: @avp, можно открыть файл единожды при запуске программы или при первой проверке. А когда нужно будет проверить, выполнить `seek` в начало (при ещё большем желании оптимизации можно даже воспользоваться `mmap` и бинарным поиском).

В конце концов, с помощью этого файла осуществляется прямой доступ к структурам ядра, так что это должно работать быстро.

Comment: Вообще, ИМХО, хорошо. что ради этого не стали заводить лишний системный вызов, а воспользовались уже существующим интерфейсом файлов.

Comment: mmap на /proc/... ??? Думаете это возможно?

Comment: @avp, да, и в самом деле, mmap не работает :(

Comment: Файлы в /proc это такой своеобразный интерфейс с ядром (еще один это /sys), а не те файлы, данные которых находятся на монтируемых носителях и  попадают в файловый кэш. Они больше похожи на character devices (например, /dev/tty)  (но, это все же отдаленная аналогия).

Answer (score 11):

Мне кажется, что абсолютно валидного, в 100% случаев работающего решения нет, кроме введения какого-то дополнительного флага, о чем Вы уже сказали.

Comment: Откровенно говоря, по-моему, проще использовать дополнительный флаг (даже с переписыванием большой части кода :)), чем вот такой код при необходимости разыменования. Тем более, что, если не ошибаюсь, любое разыменование чего угодно, кроме валидных объектов самой программы - UB.

Comment: @Harry, UB - нам необязательно разыменовывать указатель, чтобы понять, что он невалидный. А нет разыменования - нет и UB.

Comment: @Qwertiy А как понимать "Хотелось бы вывести оба этих элемента (по-разному их интерпретируя, разумеется)" из условия? Лично я понимаю так, что выводить значение и значение по адресу, если это можно - т.е. разыменовывать.

Comment: @Harry, я понимаю так: получили union, как-то магически узнали, что в нём - символ или указатель, вывели соответствующим образом. Вопрос в том, что это был за магический способ, которым мы узнали тип :)

Comment: @Qwertiy А мы и не узнали **тип**. Мы узнали в лучшем случае, что его можно трактовать как указатель. Не более того.

Comment: Я хотел просто по-возможности вывести как можно больше информации об объединении в целях отладки.
У меня просто в программе был стек, который мог хранить и символы, и строки. При добавлении или извлечении элементов из него, я хотел, чтобы они печатались на экран.

Comment: @mymedia, а что собственно с этим стеком происходило в программе? Просто без знания что хранится в элементе, символ или указатель, эти данные были бы бесполезны. Поэтому где-то в программе эта информация должна быть.

Answer (score 5):

Можно проверять, доступен ли адрес по чтению-записи, но делать выводы о том, что в Вашем union хранится все же сложно.

На всякий случай, код, который я использовал в Linux (и как ни странно, проверял в MinGW Windows-XP)

```
/*
  misc debug
 */
#include <signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#ifndef unix
#define sigjmp_buf jmp_buf
#define siglongjmp longjmp
#define sigsetjmp(buf,flag) setjmp(buf)
#endif
#ifdef __cplusplus
  static sigjmp_buf _av_is_accessible_jmp;

  static void _av_is_accessible_hdr (int sig) { 
    siglongjmp(_av_is_accessible_jmp, 0); 
  }
#endif

// check is addr readable/writable, returns 1 if so
static int
_av_is_mem_accessible (volatile char *addr, int writable)
{
  if (addr == 0 || addr == (void *)-1LL)
    return 0;
  int rc = 1;
#ifndef __cplusplus
  sigjmp_buf _av_is_accessible_jmp;

  void _av_is_accessible_hdr (int sig) { siglongjmp(_av_is_accessible_jmp, 0); }
#endif

  void 
#ifdef unix
    (* sigbus)(int) = signal(SIGBUS, _av_is_accessible_hdr), 
#endif
    (* sigsegv)(int) = signal(SIGSEGV, _av_is_accessible_hdr);

#ifdef DEBUG
#ifdef unix
  if (sigbus == SIG_ERR) {
    fputs ("SIG_ERR signal SIGBUS\n", stderr);
    exit(1);
  }
#endif
  if (sigsegv == SIG_ERR) {
    fputs ("SIG_ERR signal SIGSEGV\n", stderr);
    exit(1);
  }
#endif

  if (sigsetjmp(_av_is_accessible_jmp, 1)) { // MANDATORY save sigmask
    rc = 0;
    errno = EINVAL;
  } else {
    char t = *addr;
    if (writable)
      *addr = t;
  }

#ifdef unix
  signal(SIGBUS, sigbus);
#endif
  signal(SIGSEGV, sigsegv);

  return rc;
}
```

Идея тут состоит в том, что мы пытаемся прочесть байт по заданному адресу и если удалось, то записать его обратно. При неудаче перехватываем сигнал и возвращаем соответствующий результат.

P.S.
В gcc код реентерабельный и по идее thread-safe, а вот для крестов сделать такое не удалось...

Comment: А разве оптимизатор не может выкинуть присваивание `*addr = t`, и тогда не будет проверки на доступность записи?
И ещё мне кажется, тут есть проблема иного рода: если страница памяти, которая проверяется, была приватной, но разделяемая другими процессами с помощью механизма "копирование по записи", произойдёт ненужное копирование целой страницы, что ведёт к паденю производительности и неоптимальному расходованию физической памяти.

Comment: @mymedia, O!!! Спасибо, Вы нашли ошибочку (с оптимизацией). Уже поправил. Достаточно добавить `volatile` и все OK (по крайней мере с gcc/g++). Что же касается copy-on-write, ну, все же (imho) чаще всего проверяют на запись с целью писать туда далее, а не из пустого любопытства, так что страница все равно будет размножена. А просто для анализа можно вызывать функцию из Вашего ответа. (Реально, в моем случае этот код использовался для проверки -- передали константную строку или ее можно менять)

Comment: а почему в ++ такое нельзя? есть же даже глобальный перехватчик сегфолтов. Или расширения над try catch.

Comment: @avp: На схожую тему: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060927-07/?p=29563

Comment: @pavel, вот именно, глобальный (или статический в файле, как здесь). Проблема с потоками в статическом для С++ поле  `static sigjmp_buf _av_is_accessible_jmp;`. / А, для практического применения этой функции оттранслированной С++ (она же не вызывает какие-либо другие функции пользователя, которые могут использовать косвенную рекурсию) это сойдет (в однопоточной программе). Говоря о том, что для С++ такой подход не сработает я все же имел в виду некий общий случай использования подобного подхода. В Си (точнее GNU C) работает, поскольку тут  мы можем использовать вложенные функции.

Comment: @VladD, а я не буду спорить с автором по Вашей ссылке. Действительно, использование подобных функций для проверки **неправильных** аргументов это ошибка. Лучше просто свалиться и потом найти ошибку в вызывающем коде. Другое дело -- осознанное использование указателя для хранения разных типов, если не получается (не красиво) использовать union. Но, подобные штуки должны быть, конечно, максимально ограничены и не предназначены для "массового" использования в разных частях вызывающего кода.

Comment: @avp: Это я к тому, что сама проверка на возможность записи/чтения может обладать странными побочными эффектами. (По крайней мере в Windows.)

Answer (score 2):

Как минимум в Windows первые 64 килобайта адресного пространства отводятся специально под обработку разыменования нулевого указателя. А char - это один байт, поэтому значение в нём будет меньше 256. В таком случае при записи следует обеспечить, чтобы обнулялись остальные байты и проверять, не превосходит ли значение 255.

Приведение указателя к `int` будет некорректным в 64-битных программах, поэтому надо 256 приводить к `void *`, либо использовать нечто вроде `uintptr_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Если программа будет работать только на микроконтролерах
то можно разименовывать  любой указатель, просто будут возвращены любые данные. 
Если программа работает в ОС не используя "грязные трюки", определить допустимый адрес памяти или не допустимый, внутри программы нельзя. Только если это NULL.

Comment: На самом деле в случае архитектуры x86 или amd64 это точно возможно. Нужно только обратиться "за помощью" к операционной системе. ОС знает, какие виртуальные адреса процесса куда-нибудь отображаются. И эту информацию можно выяснить. См. пример в моём ответе.

Answer (score 0):

А нельзя ли проверить так:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

union chars
{
    char c;
    char* p;
};

void print(chars obj)
{
    (uintptr_t)tmp = (uintptr_t)obj.p;

    if ((uintptr_t)obj.p > 255)
    {
        cout << obj.p[0] << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << obj.c << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    chars c_1;
    chars c_2;

    c_1.c = 'a';
    c_2.p = "bcde";

    print(c_1);
    print(c_2);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Привести к типу int, и если значение 0-255, то в объединении символ, если больше указатель. (Указатели с трехзначными значениями ЕМНИП значениями являются системными, и динамически выделяя память, как для строк, вы их не назначите).

P.S. Решение является "костылем", подробности смотрите в комментариях.

Comment: 0. Речь только о Windows. 1. Отрицательные указатели не всегда системные - гуглить про флаг 3GB. 2. Под x64 указателю состригли 4 байта - вообще ничего гарантировать нельзя.

Comment: К сожалению, ваш код даже не компилируется: вы пытаетесь привести указатель (который на моей машние имеет размер 8 байт) к целому (размер которого составляет 4 байта). Вам следовало бы использовать специальный тип `uintptr_t`, размер которого гарантированно достаточен для хранения значений указателя. Подробнее про него вы можете прочитать на [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/). Так же вы используете функцию `system` из стандартного заголовка `<cstdlib>`, не включив его.

Comment: Но даже исправив эти ошибки, код всё равно не будет работать верно (у меня не работатет). `char` может быть как знаковым, так и беззноковым, и более того, вовсе не обязан занимать 8 бит.
Но и это ещё не всё: обычно размер char'а всё же меньше размера указателя, то когда вы присваиваете полю `c` значение типа `char`, оно заполнит лишь часть объединения, а в оставшемся куске будут старые биты указателя.

Comment: @Qwertiy,  -- 100% работающего средства, как выше указал skegg не существует. Здесь уже есть специфичные ответы, поэтому этот "костыль" тоже  имеет право на жизнь. Замечания я учту и ответ подправлю.

Comment: @mymedia -- сама постановка задачи "просит костыля", так как общего решения в принципе иметь не может, если в языке со строгой типизацией вы не знаете типа переменной, то, вы не сможете с ней работать.

Comment: @Mirdin, возможно, я криво сформулировал вопрос. Цель была — вывести максимально возможную информацию об объединении. Примерно так же, как это может делать отладчик. gdb, например, если его попросить вывести такое объединение, печатает оба поля. Причём, если указатель недействителен, выводится сообщение-заглушка, и ничего при этом не падает.

Comment: @mymedia -- в языке таких средств, насколько я знаю нет, что касается отладчика, то это внешняя программа которая, возможно: 1. хранит какую либо информацию о всех переменных, 2. использует специальный код, оставленный для него компилятором (debug/release версии кода) 3. выполняется в определенной ОС и может обращаться к специфическим функциям это ОС.

Comment: @Mirdin, совершенно верно, придётся воспользоваться третим пунктом)

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйтесь новыйми фитчами C11, а именно _Generic():

```
#define ischarprt(x) _Generic((x),                        \
        char: 0, \
      char *: 1, \
     default: -1)
```

После чего:

```
char ch = 'c';
char *prt = "pointer";
int i = 0;
if(ischarprt(prt) == 1){
    //Если данные - указатель на char
}
if(ischarprt(ch) == 0){
    //Если данные - char
}
```

Вместо чисел могут быть строки и символы.

UPD: вот ответ на ваш вопрос - [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623226/how-to-check-what-type-is-currently-used-in-union)

Comment: Ого! Да это же можно использовать как перегрузку

Comment: @mymedia конечно :) Этот вариант решения вам подходит?

Comment: @mymedia, ну а вообще, если вы пытаетесь написать динамический контейнер данных - кроме флага текущего типа в контейнере вам ничего не поможет. Но есть одна хитрость - флаги типов можно задать через enum, а однозначно идентифицировать - через _Generic(). Удачи 

Comment: @mymedia обновил ответ, теперь там есть ссылка на решение вашего вопроса.

Comment: Это не то, что нужно автору.

Comment: @dzhioev  как раз-таки это часть того, что нужно автору.

Comment: @The_Netos, нет, чтобы _Generic работал, тип нужно знать во время компиляции.

Comment: Я просто хотел показать, как можно выяснить, валиден ли указатель, без фактического разыменовывания. Собственно говоря, свою проблему я пока решил.